Handling Python Type Checker Errors with Return Type Declarations
I'm encountering an issue with my Python code using Pyright type checker, specifically when I try to remove Any from the return type declaration.
Look/read this question first: Handling Python Type Checker Errors with Return Type Declarations (fields default values = None)
Error message:
Function with declared return type "int" must return value on all code paths. "None" is incompatible with "int".

What about this case? I still get the same error as above(question from stack overflow), even though my classes do not contain any None.
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Union, List

class Exp:
    pass

@dataclass
class Const(Exp):
    value: int

@dataclass
class Negate(Exp):
    value: Exp

@dataclass 
class Add(Exp):
    value1: Exp
    value2: Exp

@dataclass
class Multiply(Exp):
    value1: Exp
    value2: Exp


def eval_exp_old(e: Exp) -> int | Any:
    match e:
        case Const(i):
            return i
        case Negate(e2):
            return -eval_exp_old(e2)
        case Add(e1, e2):
            return eval_exp_old(e1) + eval_exp_old(e2)
        case Multiply(e1, e2):
            return eval_exp_old(e1) * eval_exp_old(e2)
        

test_exp: Exp = Multiply(Negate(Add(Const(2), Const(2))), Const(7))
# -28
old_test = eval_exp_old(test_exp)

Error:
def eval_exp_old(e: Exp) -> int { ... }

I appreciate any advice.
Btw, check this article, also posted in accepted answer.
https://discuss.python.org/t/draft-pep-sealed-decorator-for-static-typing/49206

How is this different from your last question? Your match statement is still not exhaustive. Your class hierarchy is open: just because you haven't defined any other subclasses of Exp here doesn't mean you can't before eval_exp_old gets called.

@chepner is there a way to make those classes not open? I viewed this whole thing "as non editable file", do I have to make it file private or whatever python equivalent thing is?

No; your match statement just needs to have a catch-all for any subclasses you don't want to or know how to handle.

@chepner yes, makes sense. I also tried to nest subclasses in main class, still the same issue.

What if someone inherits from Exp and passes that to eval_exp_old()?
class NewExp(Exp): pass

eval_exp_old(NewExp())  # Pass type checking, yet silently returns None

Add a default case to your matching tree and throw an error in it. That way, you will get a runtime error (preferably in tests) telling you that you forgot to handle some cases:
match e:
    case Const(i):
        return i
    # ...
    case _:
        raise ValueError(f'Value {e} of type {type(e).__name__} is not expected')

Generally-speaking, what you want is called "sealed classes":
@sealed  # This means all subclasses are known ahead of time
class Exp:
    pass

This has only ever existed in a recent PEP draft and this relevant thread on the official Python forum.

I was going to ask you how is some1 even able to call this class if I'm making those classes private, but looks like in python if I am saying class _Exp is just a naming convention it does not make it private, or fileprivate or whatever. Is that the reason why is throwing this error?

@Adrian What if that "someone" is you? It is to prevent our own mistakes that we use code quality tools like type checkers, after all. You want something like Kotlin's sealed classes, but that has yet to have a Python equivalent.

Got it. I thought that the only reason that this works in Kotlin and Swift is because both are statically-typed languages, but looks like there is more than that, swift has a strong type system with exhaustive pattern matching for enums, so the compiler knows what stuff is missing and what not.
